# Problems trying to install python module: pyHook

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, pip, pyhook

I am trying to download the pyHook module in order to complete an assignment for school. I have tried looking for an answer to my problem but I haven't found it. When I try to pip install python-pyHook I get this:

```
pip install python-pyHook
Downloading/unpacking python-pyHook
   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-pyHook      
  Cleaning up...
 No distributions at all found for python-pyHook
 Storing debug log for failure in /home/goofy/.pip/pip.log
```

And when I try to sudo apt-get install python-pyHook I get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyHook
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pyHook
```

I have already run this command as well.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Am I doing this completely wrong? These are the the only implementations I could find for how to install pyHook on Ubuntu 14. Thank you for your time.

Comment: pyHook only for Windows

Comment: You can check: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pykeylogger/

Comment: Its possible to compile this in linux? for a windows in a .exe?

Answer (score 3):

pyHook is only for Windows.

There is a Linux implementation of pyHook called pyxhook. You can find the repository [here](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook).

Comment: With this implementantion, the pyHook library works on windows?